# sql query logic - sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way to improve this query..

```
INSERT INTO mastertable 
VALUES      (SELECT * 
             FROM   staging_tbl s 
             WHERE  s.pac NOT IN (SELECT pac 
                                  FROM   mastertable) 
                    AND s.store NOT IN (SELECT store 
                                        FROM   mastertable))
```

Not sure if this will work at first place.. Basically..want to select records from Staging_Tbl only if same PAC-STORE combination do not currently exist.. If PAC exist but for another STORE..yes, we should select and vice versa.
For eg: Should if MasterTable is as below,

```
PAC1  STORE1
PAC1  STORE2
PAC2  STORE1
PAC2  STORE2
```

I should insert only if there is a record like PAC1 STORE3  in the staging table..
 and NOT PAC1 STORE2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have indexes on those columns..that will make a change

you can also use NOT EXISTS

```
INSERT INTO MASTERTABLE 
 SELECT * FROM Staging_Tbl S 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM MasterTable M 
            WHERE S.STORE = M.STORE
            AND S.PAC = M.PAC)
```

Or A LEFT JOIN

```
 INSERT INTO MASTERTABLE 
 SELECT S.* FROM Staging_Tbl S 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterTable M 
    ON S.STORE = M.STORE
    AND S.PAC = M.PAC
WHERE M.PAC IS NULL
AND M.STORE IS NULL
```

Except, make sure to test performance with this one

```
INSERT INTO MASTERTABLE 
 SELECT * FROM Staging_Tbl 
 EXCEPT
 SELECT * FROM MASTERTABLE
```

I myself like NOT EXISTS the best

See also  [Select all rows from one table that don't exist in another table](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#4) for usage of OUTER APPLY and EXCEPT to do the same

Comment: The LEFT JOIN version needs some fixing. You want to select `S.*` rather than `*`.

Comment: Andriiy, he says `only if same PAC-STORE combination do not currently exist.`

Comment: My fault, you are right. I merely compared the solutions to the OP's query. Should have read the details more properly first. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT MASTERTABLE
SELECT * FROM Staging_Tbl S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM MASTERTABLE M
 WHERE M.PAC = S.PAC AND M.STORE = S.STORE)
```